# Bypass password in sharepoint for external service

Tags: rest, password

I have a external webservice that uses service account to login into sharepoint to access sharepoint apis.

The problem we had is that the password would expire every 3 month. We want to seek out a way that we can maybe use azure password vault or something to generate a permanent key that we can use to access sharepoint api.

I am not sure if this can be done or is possible. I dont even know where I can seek out resource for this. I have tried to convince security team to allow perma password but with no luck. Are there any solution which can bypass this password issue?

"Edit"
I was able to generate token from clientId and clientSecret but I am getting error 403 when I tries to connect to it. HttpUrlConnection basically tries to run a search (query) api from sharepoint.

```
            HttpURLConnection url1 = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(path).openConnection();
            logger.debug("------------------------");
            url1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
            url1.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            url1.setRequestProperty("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            url1.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            url1.setRequestMethod("GET");
            for(Entry<String, List<String>> m : url1.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("key: "+m.getKey());
                for(String v: m.getValue()) {
                    System.out.println("values: "+v);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but I'd recommend using an App-Only principal. The advantage of this approach is you can grant only the explicit permissions you need it to have. Implementation details are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs):

If you don't need full tenant access but only want to scope your app to a single site, you can use the AppRegNew and AppInv pages as described in the linked doc, but on the intended target site instead.

Comment: I have tried this. My code is written in java. I have added the edit above...